# iAds on 3.5 Iphone not appearing

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode5, sprite-kit

I have set up iAds for my app, but for whatever reason, they only appear on the iphone 4 inch and not the 3.5 inch. First, I thought it had something to do with the Auto Layout, so I made sure the BannerView appeared in both screen sizes. After doing so, I ran and still would not work.

Here is the code I used to tell the bannerView what to do. This is in the ViewController.m file.

```
#pragma mark iAd Delegate Methods

-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [banner setAlpha:1];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}


-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [banner setAlpha:0];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Also, this is being done in Spritekit if that matters.

Thanks for helping, and I'm pretty new to coding so something that may seem obvious, I might have easily not noticed.

Comment: Are you setting the frame of the ADBannerView? Are you setting the delegate? Allocating?

Comment: I have assigned the banner as the delegate.

Comment: I used this video to set it up  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fP2ijcXbCz4

Comment: Are you setting the frame?

Comment: The position of the banner is set in the storyboard

Answer (score 0):

You cannot animate the alpha of an object. Alternatively, you should be modifying it's transparency via it's opacity:

```
- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        banner.layer.opacity = 1.0f;
    }];
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        banner.layer.opacity = 0.0f;
    }];
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. I ended up answering my own question through a lot of trial and error. Now the add is placed as a subview so buttons taps on the banner aren't also read by the game.